# Ubuntu 20.04 displays the sound bar on Pavucontrol, but no audio

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently got Lambda Tensorbook with Ubuntu 20.04. I have audio devices installed (screenshots below), but the audio does not work, unfortunately.

I noticed that it's a known issue, so while I didn't understand most of the codes, I tried all the potential solutions I could find online - from `sudo apt update` to reset/reboot ALSA and PulseAudio to changing element speaker in `analog-output-lineout.conf` from off to on through `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/`, but to no avail.

Whenever I play the audio now, I do see the soundbar move in `pavucontrol,` but I still don't receive the sound with or without earphones/HDMI cable (photo below). I have spent days trying to work on this problem, but I still could not figure out any solution; thus, I will appreciate any leads on this. Thank you!

Audio driver (1/2):

[image: Audio driver (1/2)]

Audio driver (2/2):

[image: Audio driver (2/2)]

Pavucontrol:

[image: Pavucontrol]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same situation yesterday, I had no sound right after testing a new webcam. I have tried everything there is in and out of the books, but no success.

Then I had a crazy idea that came out of the blue, and reinstaled the window manager.

apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon

The sound was back. I can not explain why this worked, but it did.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not familiar with cinnamon - what do you use it for?